# MyBatis stand-alone java application "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/io/Resources" Error

Tags: mybatis

gurus!
I'm studying the basic mybatis programming(first not using Spring), but there was an interesting error.
I had 5 files( CHelloMybatis.java, hello-mybatis.xml, hello-mybatis-mapper.xml, mybatis-2.5.13.jar, postgresql-42.6.0.jar)
**"CHelloMybatis.java" is very simple standalone mybatis java application.**

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;

    public class CHelloMybatis {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String conf = "hello-mybatis.xml";
            InputStream is;
            // Reader reader;
            try {
                is = Resources.getResourceAsStream(conf);
                SqlSessionFactory sqlsessionfactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(is);
                //reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(conf);
                //SqlSessionFactory sqlsessionfactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**"hello-mybatis.xml" is for testing connection to postgresql.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
      PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
    <configuration>
        <environments default="development">
            <environment id="development">
                <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
                <dataSource type="POOLED">
                    <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.1/testdb"/>
                    <property name="username" value="testuser"/>
                    <property name="password" value="testpassword"/>
                </dataSource>
            </environment>
        </environments>
        <mappers>
            <mapper resource="hello-mybatis-mapper.xml"/>
        </mappers>
```

```
</configuration>
```

**"hello-mybatis-mapper.xml" **

```
    <mapper namespace="getting-started">
        <select id="hello" resultType="_int">
            SELECT count(*) from test
        </select>
    </mapper>
```

Compiling with java is done, when I run code with java, error is occurred as follows:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/io/Resources
at CHelloMybatis.main(CHelloMybatis.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more`The more strange thing is that : On raspberrypi(rasbian) no runtime error, On ubuntu or On centos error always occurred(when using Inputstream and Reader)`